# Function over vector not working in R

Tags: r

I want to run a function over a vector, using the `lapply()` command. This is my attempt, reproducible:

```
set.seed(10101)

# define parameters

N <- 1000
a <- 0.3

# create vector of variables

e <- rnorm(N)  
l <- rchisq(N, df = 3, ncp = 0)
k <- rbeta(N, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 5, ncp = 0)

# vector over which to run function

g <- c(1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, -0.2, -0.5, -1)

# define function

CES <- function(g,a,e){
  exp(e)*(a*l^g+(1-a)*k^g)^(1/g)
}  

# result

y <- lapply(g,CES)
```

I get the error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "e" is missing, with no default

What is the mistake? Is it due to the fact that the elements of the function (l,k,e) are themselves vectors?

Comment: you can also define the "current" values as default for your function: `CES <- function(g, a=a, e=e){...}` and then call `lapply(g, CES)`

Comment: @LeoP. the problem here is that the function has 2 arguments, with no default value, that are not specified in the call. If you don't put an input as argument, then your function will look for it in the parent environment (if `a` and `e` had not been arguments to the function, then the current values would have been used)

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking in the wrong place, trying to fix my function definition. Dumb mistake. I think I am bringing my Matlab mentality of global definitions to R. Still learning. Thank people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
y <- lapply(g, CES, a=a, e=e)
```

It is to follow the description of the error. The parameters `a=` and `e=` of your function `CES()` have no default - so you have to deliver them to the function. You can use the `...`-argument of the function `lapply()` to do that.
Alternativly (see the comment from @Cath) you can change the definition of your function:

```
CES <- function(g, a=a, e=e) exp(e)*(a*l^g+(1-a)*k^g)^(1/g)
y <- lapply(g, CES) # now works
```

or (a bad variant):

```
CES <- function(g) exp(e)*(a*l^g+(1-a)*k^g)^(1/g)
y <- lapply(g, CES) # now works
```